# Firebase Storage image URL accessible only to users with read permissions

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

When using Firebase Storage with the Javascript SDK is there a way to only let users who pass the read permissions view an image. The issue I'm running into is once I get a storage reference the only way to view the image in a browser is via the download url, which has no permissions attached to it. What I am wanting is a URL only accessible by users who pass the read permissions. Is there a way to do this currently?

Edit 1:

Currently, I am getting the url like this:

```js
        const firebaseUrl = 'gs://bucket/object';
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        storageRef.child(firebaseUrl).getDownloadURL()
          .then(url => console.log(url))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And am putting the download url in the img src.

```html
<img src="url generated from above code" />
```

How can I have the image display only if an authenticated firebase user with permissions is viewing it? If the url is viewed in an incognito window it will return a 403 or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, download URLs are always universally accessible until its token is revoked.  This behavior can't be changed.  If you need to apply security rules to a file, you have to use the SDK to download the content, since the SDK is aware of the user signed in through Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated my question with a code example if you could take a look please!

Comment: As I said, you can't change the behavior of a download URL.

Comment: I see, and there's no other way to view that url besides getting the download url?

Comment: For web, not that I know of.  On Android, you can integrate with Glide to show images without having to go through a download URL.